# svn: just trying to create and remove a folder in my local working copy

Tags: svn

I am trying to create and remove a folder in my local working copy.

These below are my steps:

```
$ mkdir jander
$ svn add jander
A         jander
$ svn rm jander
svn: Use --force to override this restriction
svn: 'jander' has local modifications
```

As you can see I'm getting that message about "use --force ...", So... am I doing something wrong? What is the correct way to create and remove a folder?

Regards,

Javi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't committed it, the folder still has local modifications, and thus the error. Do the commit, then the rm, and commit the rm, and you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

In your case You have not committed that folder. And want to rm this recently added folder then you can remove it by using

```
svn revert jander
rm jander
```